# pfSense: Bundling carp VIPs

Tags: redundancy, failover, pfsense

When configuring Carp for pfSense as recommended by their [guide](https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/highavailability/configuring-high-availability.html), [this issue](https://redmine.pfsense.org/issues/1248) appears: when pulling out the WAN cable (simulating, say, a cable failure, switch port failure, or network card failure), the WAN carp will switch, but the LAN carp will not. Meaning router #1 is connected to the LAN, and router #2 is connected to the WAN, which leads to the computers behind the configuration being disconnected. Conversely, pulling out the LAN cable can lead to an IP address change (when using 3 public IPs) or also a disconnect (when using just 1 due to address exhaustion).

In the [linked bug report](https://redmine.pfsense.org/issues/1248), the submitter commented that it quote 'was a misconfiguration' on their part. So if the default configuration is a misconfiguration: To have the VIPs failover **as a group** instead of individually, what is actually the correct configuration to get them to behave in this way? (They did not submit how they fixed their issue)

To clarify: I want:

If say only NIC #1 fails on router #1, **all** VIPs should jump from router #1 to router #2, even if everything else is still functional. (On-site personnel could then replace the defective device to ensure continued internet availability for the downstream LAN).

Comment: Do you have an actual question? This is not an appropriate place to make announcements.

Comment: @Ron Maupin It is a question: How do I configure to get the behaviour I want (multiple VIPs failover together) instead of what I have (it's possible to have only one VIP failover).

Comment: You have not actually asked a question in the post, and we have no information on how things are connected or configured, to be able to offer an answer to a question. Please edit the question to include the necessary information. You can refer to the [Network Engineering Question Checklist](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/292/8499) for guidance, then edit your question.